# Cross corridor var swap

Tags: volatility, equities, variance, exotics

How should I think about replicating a cross corridor variance swap like breaking into strips of calls and puts and an over hedge that I can rebalance at some frequency? Given the earnings move, I can define some threshold based on implied move from the listed strikes.